# HTML & CSS of two column with background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

My apology if my title is not right because I don't know how to call it, but it is important for me.. Please help... and pls. don't hesitate to tell me the right title.

[image]

The image above has full width: 2000px, this is the size of the screen, if the screen is bigger the maximum width of the center container will stay at 1366px but the page is smaller than 1366px the container width is fluid. I don't know how to put a different background image to the left and right.

thanks, really don't know how to call it that is why I can't search in google.

Comment: It is somewhat impossible to help you if you do not post your code here. Instead of a verbal explanation, you should always post a minimal example of your code.

Comment: I don't have a code, even a single code because I really confused and don't have an idea how to do it, really. please help.

Comment: Code? Just the parent div, body, html, head, that all I have.

Comment: Let's see if I understand: The backgound now is only 1 image of 2000px, but if the page is smaller than 1366, scrollbars will be added, so you dont want the backbground image move, even if you move the scrollbars?

Comment: Can you explain this better; **I don't know how to put a different background image to the left and right**. do you mean when the width is greater than 2000px you want image to fill out or you want to place other images?

Comment: Pablo, the image are divided into two, left and right because the image is editable via admin panel. 

Chris, yes, the left and right image background will fill the screen doesn't matter the size.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if i understand your question but i would make a left and right container for each section but as you probably don't want to or can't

you can use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

```
.multi_bg_example {
  background-image: url(""),
  background-image: url("");

  background-repeat  : no-repeat,
                       no-repeat;

  background-position: center left,
                       center right;
  background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%;
}
```

This is untested but should get you on the right track